# MySQL: difference between two dates based on states

Tags: mysql, datediff

i have a table with records like this

| ID | UID | LOKACIJA | STATUS | TS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16520 | 306 | 1 | 1 | 31.05.2022 23:20 |
| 16521 | 306 | 1 | 0 | 31.05.2022 23:28 |
| 16522 | 306 | 1 | 1 | 31.05.2022 23:31 |
| 16523 | 306 | 1 | 0 | 31.05.2022 23:35 |

I would like to calculate the time from status 1 to status 0.
1 is the startdate and 0 is the enddate.
So the result need to be like this:

Time 1 = 8 min
Time 2 = 4 min

Does anyone have any ideas for the query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select timestampdiff(minute,t1.ts,t2.ts) tdiff from
(select row_number() over (order by null) rn,ts from table_1 where status=1) t1 inner join
(select row_number() over (order by null) rn, ts from table_1 where status=0) t2
where t1.rn=t2.rn
```

Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uhQbhvMcfPNWa7CJFHxwiX/0)

Adding, another variation -

```
select * from (
select timestampdiff(minute,ts,
lead(case when status=0 then ts end) over (order by null)
) ts                     
from table_1)t
where t.ts is not null
```